# Regex pattern to find n non-space characters of x length after a certain substring

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using this regex pattern `pattern = r'cig[\s:.]*(\w{10})'` to extract the 10 characters after the '''cig''' contained in each line of my dataframe. With this pattern I am accounting for all cases, except for the ones where that substring contains some spaces inside it.

For example, I am trying to extract `Z9F27D2198` from the string

```
/BENEF/FORNITURA GAS FEB-20 CIG Z9F                 27D2198 01762-0000031
```

In the previous string, it seems like Stack overflow formatted it, but there should be 17 whitespaces between `F` and `2`, after `CIG`.

Could you help me to edit the regex pattern in order to account for the white spaces in that 10-characters substring? I am also using `flags=re.I` to ignore the case of the strings in my `re.findall` calls.

To give an example string for which this pattern works:

```
CIG7826328A2B FORNITURA ENERGIA ELETTRICA U TENZE COMUNALI CONVENZIONE CONSIP E
```

and it outputs what I want: `7826328A2B`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `cig[\s:.]*(\S(?:\s*\S){9})(?!\S)`

Comment: Using Wiktor's regex: https://regex101.com/r/nL8ZoN/1 you'd need to strip out the whitespace afterwards as regex matches are consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'(?i)cig[\s:.]*(\S(?:\s*\S){9})(?!\S)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QpxQu/1). *Details*:

- `cig` - a `cig` string
- `[\s:.]*` - zero or more whitespaces, `:` or `.`
- `(\S(?:\s*\S){9})` - Group 1: a non-whitespace char and then nine occurrences of zero or more whitespaces followed with a non-whitespace char
- `(?!\S)` - immediately to the right, there must be a whitespace or end of string.

In Python, you can use

```py
import re
text = "/BENEF/FORNITURA GAS FEB-20 CIG Z9F               27D2198 01762-0000031"
pattern = r'cig[\s:.]*(\S(?:\s*\S){9})(?!\S)'
matches = re.finditer(pattern, text, re.I)
for match in matches:
  print(re.sub(r'\s+', '', match.group(1)), ' found at ', match.span(1))

# => Z9F27D2198  found at  (32, 57)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ykcie9).

Comment: This works, thank you! However, I need to take off the 'CIG' at the beginning, i.e. my output should only be 'Z9F27D2198', without formatting or slicing the result (I know I could do match.group()[-10:], but I want to account for that in the regex pattern, and same goes for the indexes.

Comment: @MassimilianoGarzoni Just use `.group(1)` and `.span(1)`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, however the index start still refers to where the C happens. Also, how does group(1) work?

Comment: @MassimilianoGarzoni No, the `.span(1)` yields the start/end indices of Group 1, not the whole match. Count the chars, and you will see. `.group(1)` shows the contents captured with the first capturing group, `span(1)` yields its start/end indices.

Comment: Thanks. I do still have some cases that this pattern is still not accounting for. For example, for the string `CIG79479586DBPAGAMENTO FATTURA N. FE000120200000506427`. See the [https://regex101.com/r/8xI7sN/1]regex demo.

Comment: @MassimilianoGarzoni If you do not need to make sure the 10 numbers are followed with a whitespace or end of string, simply remove `(?!\S)`.

Comment: I tried that before but I saw the regex tester settings where different and it didn't work. Now it does, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
# removes all white spaces with replace()

x = 'CIG7826328A2B FORNITURA ENERGIA ELETTRICA U'.replace(' ', '')
x = x.split("CIG")[1][:10] 
# x = '7826328A2B'

x = '/BENEF/FORNITURA GAS FEB-20 CIG Z9F 27D2198 01762-0000031'.replace(' ', '')
x.split("CIG")[1][:10]
# x = '7826328A2B'
```

Works fine if there is only one "CIG" in the string

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep, originally I actually splitted the strings to whitespaces and found the substring i was looking for each one of them. The problem is that I need to keep the original formatting as to save the start and end indexes of the match, when I call re.finditer(). Also the string actually contains more whitespaces; stackoverflow formats it.